# RegEx to check not to have a sentence

Tags: java, regex, groovy

I have the `regex1 = "^Line\\s(?:(\\d+)\\s)?\\s*:\\s+(\\d+)?.+";` to match below lines in Groovy

```
def msg1 = "Line : 1 Invoice does not foot Reported"
def msg2 = "Line : 2 Could not parse INVOICE_DATE value"
def msg5 = "Line 3 : Could not parse ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT value"
def msg6 = "Line 4 : MATH ERROR"
```

Now am trying to match the messages which doesnt have `Invoice does not foot Reported` sentence, so I tweaked the regex as below

```
def regex2 = "^Line\\s(?:(\\d+)\\s)?\\s*:\\s+(\\d+)?((?!Invoice does not foot Reported).).+"
```

When I do the `msg1.matches(regex2)` am getting the result as true instead of true instead of false.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the negative lookahead just after to the second `\d+` and don't foget to put `.*?` inside the negative lookahead assertion.

```
"^Line\\s(?:(\\d+)\\s)?\\s*:\\s+(\\d+)?(?!.*?\\bInvoice does not foot Reported).+"
```

**Example:**

```
String msg1 = "Line : 1 Invoice does not foot Reported";
String msg2 = "Line : 2 Could not parse INVOICE_DATE value";
String msg5 = "Line 3 : Could not parse ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT value";
String msg6 = "Line 4 : MATH ERROR";
System.out.println(msg1.matches("Line\\s(?:(\\d+)\\s)?\\s*:\\s+(\\d+)?(?!.*?\\bInvoice does not foot Reported).+"));
System.out.println(msg2.matches("Line\\s(?:(\\d+)\\s)?\\s*:\\s+(\\d+)?(?!.*?\\bInvoice does not foot Reported).+"));
System.out.println(msg5.matches("Line\\s(?:(\\d+)\\s)?\\s*:\\s+(\\d+)?(?!.*?\\bInvoice does not foot Reported).+"));
System.out.println(msg6.matches("Line\\s(?:(\\d+)\\s)?\\s*:\\s+(\\d+)?(?!.*?\\bInvoice does not foot Reported).+"));
```

**Output:**

```
false
true
true
true
```

Comment: If I also want to exclude other words can I do like this `^Line\\s(?:(\\d+)\\s)?\\s*:\\s+(\\d+)?(?!.*?\\bInvoice does not foot Reported|MATH ERROR).+`

Comment: no , it would be `^Line\\s(?:(\\d+)\\s)?\\s*:\\s+(\\d+)?(?!.*?(?:\\bInvoice does not foot Reported|MATH ERROR)).+` , `.*?` part inside the negative lookahead should be common for both strings.

Comment: can you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29496208/regex-to-match-specific-words-and-ignore-specific-text