# RegEx to match specific words and ignore specific text

Tags: java, regex, groovy

i have a list of below error messages

```
def errorMessages = ["Line : 1 Invoice does not foot Reported"
                     "Line : 2 Could not parse INVOICE_DATE value"
                     "Line 3 : Could not parse ADJUSTMENT_AMOUNT value"
                     "Line 4 : MATH ERROR"
                     "cl_id is a required field"
                     "File Error : The file does not contain delimiters"
                     "lf_name is a required field"]
```

Am trying to create a new list which doesnt match the `regex "^Line\\s(?:(\\d+)\\s)?\\s*:\\s+(\\d+)?.+"` but has the text `Invoice does not foot Reported`

my desired new list should be like below

```
def headErrors= ["Line : 1 Invoice does not foot Reported"
                 "cl_id is a required field"
                 "File Error : The file does not contain delimiters"
                 "lf_name is a required field"]
```

this is what am doing for now

```
regex = "^Line\\s(?:(\\d+)\\s)?\\s*:\\s+(\\d+)?.+"
errorMessages.each{
    if(it.contains('Invoice does not foot Reported'))
        headErrors.add(it)
    else if(!it.matches(regex)
        headErrors.add(it)
}
```

Is there a way it can be done just using regex instead of if else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. At first match the line which contains the text `Invoice does not foot Reported` in the message part.
2. Then use a negative lookahead assertion at the start to not to  match a line if it is startswith the chars which are actually matched by `Line\\s(?:(\\d+)\\s)?\\s*:\\s+(\\d+)?` pattern.

Regex:

```
"^Line\\s(?:(\\d+)\\s)?\\s*:\\s+(\\d+)?.*?Invoice does not foot Reported.*|^(?!Line\\s(?:(\\d+)\\s)?\\s*:\\s+(\\d+)?.*).+"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vG3hL4/3)

Comment: It looks fine when testing manually on `regex101.com` but when I use it in my code compiler is giving below error `illegal string body character after dollar sign; solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" `

Comment: remove the `$` sign and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I appreciate it. Can you also help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570648/java-8-find-and-replace-matching-strings